# Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)

Tags: ios, ssl, certificate

I have a problem similar to this: [Apple Push Notification in Production Environment : Unable to get local issuer certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11500684/apple-push-notification-in-production-environment-unable-to-get-local-issuer-c)
but in my local computer.
I followed this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12 but in this step

```
openssl s_client -connect gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 -cert PushChatCert.pem -key PushChatKey.pem
```

It says:

> (A lot of number and letters)
>   Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)

What the problem is? Thank you

Answer (score 15):

The problem is you are using the "sandbox" APNS server which is used for development.

In order to test the production certificates you have to connect to the production APNS server. You can use the address:

`gateway.push.apple.com:2195` instead of `gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195`

Comment: I have this same problem, but I am using development certificates though @gabcas

Comment: Make sure you've followed the [correct steps](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12) to create/export the development certificates. Also, you could try production certificates and production server. Please let us know if you find there was another cause to the error.

Comment: In turns out the error was that, I was using a password with the private key, I thought it was necessary, since Keychain Access asked for one, but when I created a new private key without a password, everything worked. :)

Answer (score 15):

This *is not* a problem.  This, in fact, is confirmation that your certificate is working.  If it were to not work you would get something like this:

```
unable to load client certificate private key file
<XXXXX>:error:<XXXX>:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:evp_enc.c:539:
<XXXXX>:error:<XXXX>:PKCS12 routines:PKCS12_pbe_crypt:pkcs12 cipherfinal error:p12_decr.c:104:
<XXXXX>:error:<XXXX>:PKCS12 routines:PKCS12_item_decrypt_d2i:pkcs12 pbe crypt error:p12_decr.c:130:
<XXXXX>:error:<XXXX>:PEM routines:PEM_READ_BIO_PRIVATEKEY:ASN1 lib:pem_pkey.c:132:
```

See this tutorial for an example 
http://lessons.runrev.com/s/lessons/m/4069/l/53405-how-do-i-use-push-notifications-with-ios

Or if you want to hear it from ray
http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=380&p=7734

There is an explanation of what is going on here: [OpenSSL: unable to verify the first certificate for Experian URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7587851/openssl-unable-to-verify-the-first-certificate-for-experian-url)

Essentially though, the cert would work if you were using a client that supported certificate discovery, and you don't need openssl to work, just to confirm that you made your cert right, and you've done that.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are using development certificate, you need to use apple development IOS push service certificate and also you need to create .p12 from this certificate, not from development certificate.