# How to issue Development MDM APNS Certificate?

Tags: apple-push-notifications, mdm

Regarding [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ProvisioningDevelopment/ProvisioningDevelopment.html):

We need 2 separate certificates, one for production, one for development. We have issued the production certificate and it works ok with Production APNS, but not with development when we setup the development APNS in MDM payload.

Any idea how to issue development APNS certificate?

Comment: You create the certificates the same way for each environment. To quote your link: `To create a certificate for the production environment, repeat the same procedure but choose the application ID for the production certificate.`

Answer (score 0):

In the iOS provisioning portal, select 'App IDs'.  Click on 'configure' next to your app name.  And once your app is enabled to send push notifications, you can configure and download your push development certificate.

Remember that your app can not contain a wildcard (*) in the bundle identifier.

This [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12) helped me a lot.

Also, remember to switch between the development APNS and production APNS.  I show how to do this on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11558177/verify-return-code-20-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate/13433687#13433687).